# use gitlab.com to deploy to private server

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have not been able to figure out if I can use gitlab.com (the website, not a private run version) and their community runners to deploy and run a node.js app to a private server.

What I need to achieve should be pretty simple:

login to server
clone/fetch master
npm install
npm start

This is my first time setting up any CI myself so would love some help